# Python os.scandir() returns file or directory not found

Tags: python, operating-system

I am developing a flask app that scans a directory on local disk and performs some file operations. It works very well in Windows, but when I deploy to DigitalOcean (Linux) it gives the following error:

```
for file in os.scandir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/my/directory/path'
```

The directory created in my Windows is:

```
D:\my\directory\path
```

So when I use the UNIX path for it `/my/directory/path` because my project is on my D disk so it considers it as root, it works perfectly.

On Linux, I literally just created the same path `/my/directory/path`, and it says directory not found.

Here is my code:

```
def get_files(path):
    print("CHECKING THE PATH: ", path)
    for file in os.scandir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)):
            print("FILE YIELDED IS: ", file)
            yield file
```

***UPDATE:***

The complete log is:

```
Job "sync_work_days (trigger: interval[0:00:05], next run at: 2022-07-16 13:08:01 UTC)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/app/app/sftp.py", line 19, in sync_work_days
    for file in get_files(files_path):
  File "/app/app/sftp.py", line 9, in get_files
    for file in os.scandir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tasbiq/files/renault'
```

The complete function is:

```
def sync_work_days():
    files_path = "/tasbiq/files/renault"

    print("FILES LISTED ARE: ", get_files(files_path))
    files = []
    for file in get_files(files_path):
        print(f"STEP 1: {file} is found")
        files.append(file)
    
    if files == []:
        print("STEP 1BIS: DIRECTORY EMPTY")
        return "empty"
    else:
        for f in files:
            if f.name.endswith('.csv'):
                print(f"STEP 2: CSV FILE {f} FOUND")
                randomint = str(random.randint(1000,9999))
                datenow = str(datetime.now().date())
                fpath = files_path + '/' + f.name
                print(f"STEP 2: file path is {fpath}")

                upload_working_days(fpath)
                print("STEP 2BIS: uploading days finished")
                newpath = files_path + '/archive/' + f.name + '-' + datenow + '-' + randomint
                os.rename(fpath, newpath)
                print(f"STEP 3: file renamed from {fpath} to {newpath}")
```

***UPDATE 2:***

I tried the scandir function in a standalone python file and it worked, but it's not working when it's used in the Flask project. FYI: I'm using Docker annd gunicorn. Here's a screenshot of my test:

[image]

***UPDATE 3:***
Replicated the exact same function independently and it worked:
[image]

Comment: what's the output of the print statements? Also, use `ls` or a command line tool to make sure the file actually exists. Also, curious as to why you're looping through the entire directory to find a file whose name you already know?

Comment: check the`basepath`, try providing the complete path

Comment: The absolute path is /tasbiq/files/renault/. I don't know the name of the file as someone else will put the file in there via SFTP, but the file should be a CSV one. I added the output of the print statement, and when I use ls, or pwd, I see that the directory does exist. Doesn't this have anything to do with permissions? Maybe gunicorn should be ran by the same user who created the folder? Because both are root. But I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I will add another update, I tested the scandir alone and it worked, so something else must be the problem: FYI: I'm using Docker and gunicorn

Comment: Added another screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The problem is actually with Docker. As the docker image I'm running is an isolated container, it cannot access local directories of the machine. I need to mount a volume in Docker and point it to the local directory. After that, I should use the mounted volume to access my data.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/